# How can I hide the WHO covid-19 banner on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

How can I hide the WHO covid-19 banner on YouTube?

[image]

Video: https://youtu.be/gAk7aX5hksU

---

Brief description of my search/research efforts: searched on Google, found nothing.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @Rubén sure, added.

Comment: Close voter: what is unclear?

Comment: Searched *what* on Google?

Comment: @TRiG "hide the WHO covid-19 banner on YouTube"

Comment: Why would Google tell you?  That would be like searching on Bing "how do I switch to google"?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica sorry you're right, Google would never tell me how to change YouTube's default settings.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt not sure which side you're taking, but try asking Google how to prevent autoplay on playlists :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

On desktop browsers one way to block this is using the [uBlock origin extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en). Right click after installing it, and select "block element". The element you want to block is:

```
###clarify-box > .ytd-watch-flexy.style-scope
```

From your screenshot, it seems you are browsing youtube using the chrome web-browser, but with "[Desktop site](https://www.techbout.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/switch-back-to-mobile-site-chrome-android.png)" enabled, is that right? If you turn that off it should not be displayed

Answer (score 10):

On Firefox on Windows 10, you can do this without installing any plugins.  In this folder,

```
C:\Users\<your Windows login username>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\chrome\
```

create a folder named "chrome".  Inside this folder, create a file with the name userChrome.css.  Add this to it:

```
#clarify-box > .ytd-watch-flexy.style-scope {
    display: none;
}
```

This technique allows you to modify the css of any part of any site, not just YouTube.

Answer (score 4):

As a complement to [oaeide](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/50331/oaeide)'s [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/140930/18147), one can use oaeide's code with  [Adblock Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus-free-ad-bloc/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb) Chrome extension:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @mbomb007 Oh, I use Firefox. But "anyone who has ever […] opened the settings once" is probably just over half of ABP users… hmm… Actually, ABP does make it much clearer than I thought it did.

Answer (score 1):

Very easy way. I did it on Firefox and Brave. The banner has several parts. 
For Brave: Right click on Covid 19 banner.
On pop-up point to Brave (or your adblocker installed) - Block element via selector - on new pop-up click OK. Repeat it for each part.
For Firefox you need uBlock Origin installed. Right click on Covid 19 banner. 
On pop-up point to uBlock Origin icon. On next pop-up click Create. Repeat it for each part.